# How to disable address bar showing on js events in IE 11 on Windows 8.1

Tags: javascript, html, windows-8.1, internet-explorer-11

There is a web application (basically a web page coming from the server), which was developed for a client using *MS Surface* tablets, which were running *Windows RT*.

When there was a shortcut (tile) pinned to the start screen of the tablet and client run it from there, it looked like any other metro app - no address bar until user dragged edge up or down.

The client started using *Windows 8.1* with *IE 11*. Now, when the user interacts with web page or javascript shows/hides something, address bar pops up from the bottom edge and hides some content.

Is there any way to make this page not to show this address bar popup?

All the application is on one page and there is even no ajax requests during the typical use. It is not possible to reconfigure all the user's existing and future tablets. So it has to be done using js or HTML.

Comment: so, basicly, you want a guaranteed Fullscreen Mode ?

Comment: Basically, it would be enough if it wouldn't show this bar during user interaction with application. When app loads new page, it would be understandable and ok (and it worked this way before). Normally everything in tablet browser happens in fullscreen anyway, just this visiting popup address bar is really annoying now.

Comment: Can you define "interaction"? What if you put everything in an `<iframe>`, would it help?

Comment: Interaction - when user presses a button (labelled "next" located in bottom right corner - that's why this problem appears), javascript (jQuery) hides a div and shows another one. This iframe idea is good one, I'll try it.

Answer (score 0):

Try Calling the App Main Page with menubar, toolbar, location, directories and status excluded from the Default page.

*From Default.html*

```
window.open('YourAppMainPage.html','_blank',
'resizable=no,menubar=no,toolbar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=no');
```

Comment: Where did you take it from? This script just opens requested page in another tab

Comment: the above script should open requested page in a new window with address bar disabled. if you want a full screen in IE, then use the kiosk mode. ie::::
iexplore.exe -k "required url"

Comment: It's all about desktop mode, but the question is about metro mode